# How can I calculate the right capacitance value if I have voltage, current, watts and power factor?

Tags: power, capacitor, calculation

I have test results.  As we can see, there is a lot of information about voltage, current, watts, capacitance, etc.

[image]

I have tried to calculate the capacitance value (Cap./Ind.) in the picture, but I can't calculate the same value of the capacitance from the picture.

For example:

We have 2.5kV, 6.744mA , 5.018Watts, PF=0.0744,and 1784.13pF in this picture, and in my opinion, we  have apparent power\$=\frac{5.018}{0.0744}=67.446VA\$,and \$\theta=cos^{-1} (0.0744)=85.73\$

And \$ VAR= VA  \times sin(85.73) =67.446 \times sin(85.73)= 67.258=\frac{V^2}{X_c}=V^2 \times 2\pi f C \$,

so \$C=\frac{67.258}{V^2 2 \pi f }=\frac{67.258}{2.5^2 \times 377 }\times 10^{-6}=28544.5pF \neq 1784.13pF\$

I have no idea that how to calculate the capacitance value. Does anyone have some other opinion?  Can anyone teach me how to calculate the right capacitance value from voltage, current and watts?

Comment: I couldn't understand anything from the shown values. So is it something like 2.5 kV is applied somewhere, and 6.744 mA current is read? This makes 16.86 VA (or Watts, I don't know). If the measured real power is 5.018 W, and if we take the previous 16.86 as volt-amps then this doesn't make a PF of 0.0744. Also, if there's Watts then there can't be pure capacitance i.e. there must be a resistive component (wire resistance, ESR/DCR etc).

Comment: @RohatKılıç sorry .i edited the question now ,i turn the VA into VAR,this should be right,but still the capacitance value is wrong

Comment: Please add a schematic diagram to make the data understandable.

Comment: i only have this data,so i don't have any schematic diagram